# Floating log sdk on Android

Tags: android

Is there any available SDK for logging in a floating window on Android. 
I'm working on a device which can not be connected by usb cable,so it can't be debugged with ADB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the many [logcat apps on play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=logcat).